Es posible usar distintas versiones de Java a la vez?
Muy buenas, como dice mi pregunta, trabajo en una plataforma que usa aplicaciones de java 6, y ahora una nueva que usa java 8, es posible poder abrir las dos sin necesidad de cambiar desde variables de entorno de una a otra? gracias.

Sí, es posible. Pero se necesitan muchos más detalles para poder ayudarte en tu caso concreto. Ten en cuenta que las aplicaciones java están compiladas y el IDE (o el jenkins, o el pipeline de gitlab o lo que sea) te las va a compilar con el jdk que tú le indiques.

Si estamos hablando de aplicaciones web que se despliegan en un servidor determinado, puede que dicho servidor no sea totalmente compatible con todas las versiones java que quieras a la vez. Es decir, determinadas librerías que hayas usado puede que estén o no disponibles en ese servidor y que tengas que aplicar algún parche muy específico para conseguir que funcione.

Para solucionar eso se usa kubernetes, que te permite desplegar tus aplicaciones 6 en un servidor 6 y tus aplicaciones 8 en un servidor 8. En resumen que tu pregunta es demasiado amplia como para poder responderla adecuadamente, me temo

Sí, pero hasta el momento ¿qué has intentado?
